# Minimum output current of DC-DC

Tags: dc-dc-converter

This question is a result of several bad decisions compounded by rush implementation. It is similar to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/70146/187920), unfortunately the answers there provide only explanation, not the solution.

I had to add isolation to the UART port on already assembled boards. Luckily, the boards had small patch of unused holes just for this kind of contingency. I ordered and installed cheapest isolators ([SI8422AB-D-IS](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/si841x-2x-datasheet.pdf)) and DC-DC converters ([PDSE1-S5-S3-S](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pdse1-s.pdf)). It is only when I found 3.75V on the isolator I realized that the converter has unregulated output. It needs at least 150 mA load to drop to rated voltage, and isolator draws no more than 5 mA. So, I added LDOs ([MCP1700-3302E](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP1700-Low-Quiescent-Current-LDO-20001826E.pdf)) to the mix.

Now there is a stable 3.3V with insignificant ripple. However I also found "minimum output current 30 mA" in the converter datasheet.

Question: Should I leave it be as it is? Seems to be working fine.
Is adding 150 Ohm load resistor before or after LDO a bad idea?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVOfTi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that these boards will be used mostly for software development. The final product will have a single [ISOW7821](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/isow7821.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1590785420505) chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical reason for a minimum load is that the leakage inductance in the magnetics causes the output voltage to be significantly higher than the nominal output voltage when lightly loaded.

That could exceed the maximum input voltage of your LDO or (conceivably, but not likely) some maximum inside the DC-DC converter. I think the latter is quite unlikely, and they even specify the no-load input current, so if you have plenty of margin on the LDO, I think you’ll be okay.

Comment: I see. Well, interpolation of the max "Tolerance Envelope Curve" gives about 3.7V at no load, which is exactly what I've seen without LDO. The LDO maximum is 6V, so I am going with this and leaving everything as it is now. Thanks!